# Detect unused AMD dependencies

Tags: dependencies, amd, jshint

Is there any tool that can analyze my files for unused AMD modules so that I can clean up my code if I remove a previously used dependency?

I know to a certain degree jshint can do this with the `unused` option, but setting it to `true` ignores unused deps followed by a used one. As well as it does not actually analyze the deps array, just the function arguments.

Also setting it to `strict` isn't really practical for other parts of my code as I need that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made good use of [grunt-amdcheck](https://github.com/mehdishojaei/grunt-amdcheck). While it defaults to automatically removing unused dependencies, that doesn't work for me. So I run it with `removeUnusedDependencies: false`, which just lists the unused deps to standard out.

Comment: Yeah, I actually found that recently myself. Could have answered my own question, just forgot about it. amdcheck wasn't around at the time of asking the question.

Answer (score 0):

Now [grunt-amdcheck](https://github.com/mehdishojaei/grunt-amdcheck) is working fine and uses AST to find out unused dependencies.